# Poetry and Pyenv versioning issue

Tags: python, python-poetry, pyenv

Can someone explain to me what is going on here?

I'm trying to get pyenv and poetry to place nice together. I am on an AWS instance of `Ubuntu 20.04` which has `python 3.8.10` installed. (I have removed all traces of python2 from the system). I would like to use python 3.10 but I can't just upgrade to that (thank you very much Amazon). So enter `pyenv`.

I made an empty project with the `poetry new` command and here is the `pyproject.toml` file.

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "test"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["ken <crowmagnumb@gmail.com>"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"


[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

I have 3.10.7 installed through pyenv. If I run `poetry run python --version` I get the following output.

```
The currently activated Python version 3.8.10 is not supported by the project (^3.10).
Trying to find and use a compatible version. 
Using python3 (3.10.7)
Python 3.8.10
```

It finds and "uses" 3.10.7 but then reports 3.8.10? Huh?

If I then run `poetry env use 3.10` and try again I get ...

```
Current Python version (3.8.10) is not allowed by the project (^3.10).
Please change python executable via the "env use" command.
```

... and it fails to run completely, i.e. no version reported from the python command. How is my current python version still 3.8.10. If I run `python --version` at the command-line straight away (not through poetry), I get `3.10.7`. What is going on here?!

As a check if I run `poetry env use system` then I indeed get back to my first problem. :(

Comment: Did you install Poetry with the pyenv 3.10 Python?

Comment: No it was with the system python. I installed poetry, and then decided I needed pyenv.

Comment: So once Poetry is installed with Pyenv's Python, and using that version, do you still have the issue?

Comment: Well now that works fine. Thank you. But that seems like a bug to me no? If you create an answer I can thumb it up. But it should have an explanation.  :)

Comment: Wait! Now if I go to another directory, with another pyproject.toml file I get the old error again!

Comment: Aah. It had an old environment (I guess). I did a `poetry env remove 3.1` and then `poetry install` in that directory, and now the command works.

Comment: I guess it depends on your view whether you consider it a bug. Poetry can install Python packages for you, but it can't install another Python version. So while Python 3.10 is listed as a dependency, that is not something Poetry can fix for you (in contrast to e.g. a specific NumPy version). Since Poetry itself depends on Python, it probably gets confused, since it runs with/depends on 3.8. I find it hard to say whether that's a bug, or a design decision. There's probably a (closed) issue on its development site about it, with some reasoning as to how and why.

Comment: you just need to switch the version you installed with pyenv by running `pyenv global 3.10`. After that your poetry command will work because it specifies that you should use python 3.10.

Comment: "I would like to use python 3.10 but I can't just upgrade to that (thank you very much Amazon)": that is not because of Amazon, but because you are running Ubuntu 20.04. Ubuntu usually doesn't do minor Python upgrades in the same version of Ubuntu, since that may break things. If you want to use a more recent version of Python overall, use a more recent OS: Ubuntu 22.04 has Python 3.10, *and* is Long-term support (LTS).

Comment: Please add information about the Poetry version you are using and the output of `poetry config --list` to your post.

Answer (score -1):

You have python 3.10 install when is great, but the system version of python still exist. What you have to do now is to switch the python version you have just installed.
you can run

`pyenv global 3.10` this will switch to the 3.10 version you just installed
After that you can run your poetry command and it will work since your `pyproject.toml` specifies that you need to use the python3.10

In the future if you need to use another version of python install it with `pyenv install 3.x` and the switch to it with `pyenv global 3.x`

You can also use `local` instead of `global` if you're in the working directory and don't want to make the version your global python version

Comment: That doesn't work if Poetry is not installed for Pyenv's 3.10, but is the system Poetry (which still uses 3.8). The OP mentions that `python --version` already shows 3.10.7, so presumably, they have already set up their system to use 3.10 globally.

Comment: You don't need to install poetry for every version of python in order to use it. Once a python 3 compatible version of poetry is installed you can use it with any python 3 version. You can even use it with a `conda` environment if you want to. As long as the environment activated is is the same as specified in the `pyproject.toml`. @9769953, try it and you'll see.

Comment: If the OP did not set a global or local version for 3.10, why then does their `python --version` command show `3.10.7`?

Comment: That is because he did `poetry run python --version` which will give him the environment specified in the pyproject.toml which he is supposed to use not the environment on his system.

Comment: No, they didn't. Quoting from the question "If I run python --version at the command-line straight away (*not through poetry*), I get 3.10.7" (emphasis mine).

Comment: Please read the question well, right under the pyproject.toml file he says this. `I have 3.10.7 installed through pyenv. If I run poetry run python --version I get the following output.`

Comment: He also add this error. The currently activated Python version 3.8.10 is not supported by the project (^3.10).
Trying to find and use a compatible version. 
Using python3 (3.10.7)
Python 3.8.10

Comment: `poetry run python --version` results in multiple lines of (confusing) output. The last line of that output shows "Python 3.8.10", which is the type of output you get from `python --version`. Thus, they are still running 3.8. Besides, your comment doesn't explain my quoted point about `python --version` (not through poetry) showing 3.10.7.

Comment: I don't think you understand this very much. have you tried it locally to verify what I am saying

Comment: I'm happy to run it locally, but please first explain the result  of `python --version` when run without poetry (see my previous comment).

Comment: running `python --version` gives you the system version of python (or the current activated environment version of python). running `poetry run python --version` should give you the version of python that poetry need to run the project referencing from the `pyproject.toml` file. If that version is not activated it will compare what is available and raise an error if is doesn't match. I hope this answers your question

Comment: Indeed. So the OP sees 3.10.7 as their system version (given the penultimate paragraph). Which is equivalent to having set `pyenv global 3.10` or `pyenv local 3.10`. So they are already using 3.10, yet Poetry fails.